# convert Object to array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Have object look like this:

[image]

Need to creacte something like this

```
var newarr = [1,2]
```

In array must be added just only VALUE from object

Comment: again, please add the object in text form.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: You're trying to convert an array of object to an array?

Comment: `var yourArray=yourObject.map(function(item){return item.value});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newarr = obj.map((elem) => { return elem.value });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const newArr = oldArr.map((item) => item.value)
```

Map each **item** of **oldArr** and return **value** property of that item.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping an Array to another array is a fairly frivolous task in JavaScript

`var newarr = oldarr.map(function(element) { return element.value });`

Using ES6's array function syntax:

`var newarr = oldarr.map(element => element.value);`

You can also use the classic loop

`var newarr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < oldarr.length; i++) newarr.push(oldarr[i].value)`